# How to set goals for Locust?

Tags: locust

We have a Locust load/performance test running (in a docker-compose setup).
It now runs on our build-server.

Ideally we would like the build-job to fail if certain requirements are not met.

For example require a certain average response time, or a minimum number of requests within a given timeout.

The expections/requirements must be compared with the aggregated data. So not in the individual (python) test methods.

One option can be to parse the generated reports, but I imagine locust has built-in support for the feature I'm thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [locust-plugins](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/), specifically the custom command line options like `--check-rps`, `--check-fail-ratio` and `--check-avg-response-time`

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/cmd_line_examples.sh

Comment: Thanks! I'd suggest to explain somewhere that you need an `import locust_plugins` in your `locustfile.py` file. 
I also had some difficulties with users: pip plugins in docker get installed with a different user then the locust process. So for a few hours locust couldnt find your plugins.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of automated KPI validation, you could create a custom plugin using locust’s event hooks and its inner statistics. The overall plugin design is pretty simple:

1. Register quitting event
2. Get all statistics and serialize them
3. Calculate missing metrics (RPS, percentiles, …)
4. Check provided KPI definition
5. Validate provided KPI agains actual measurements

The whole KPI plugin code looks like this:

```
import logging
from enum import Enum
from typing import List

import locust.env
from locust.stats import calculate_response_time_percentile


class Metric(Enum):
    EROR_RATE = 'error_rate'
    PERCENTILE_90 = 'percentile_90'
    RPS = 'rps'

    @staticmethod
    def has_value(item):
        return item in [v.value for v in Metric.__members__.values()]


class KpiPluigin:
    def __init__(
            self,
            env: locust.env.Environment,
            kpis: List,
    ):
        self.env = env
        self.kpis = kpis
        self.errors = []
        self._validate_kpis()

        events = self.env.events
        events.quitting.add_listener(self.quitting)  # pyre-ignore

    def quitting(self, environment):
        serialized_stats = self.serialize_stats(self.env.stats)
        updated_stats = self._update_data(serialized_stats)
        self._kpi_check(updated_stats)
        self._interpret_errors()

    def serialize_stats(self, stats):
        return [stats.entries[key].serialize() for key in stats.entries.keys() if
                not (stats.entries[key].num_requests == 0 and stats.entries[key].num_failures == 0)]

    def _update_data(self, stats):
        for stat in stats:
            stat['error_rate'] = self._calculate_fail_rate(stat)
            stat['percentile_90'] = self._calculate_percentile(stat, 0.90)
            stat['rps'] = self._calculate_rps(stat)
        return stats

    def _calculate_rps(self, stat):
        rps = stat['num_reqs_per_sec']
        num_of_measurements = len(rps)
        return sum(rps.values()) / num_of_measurements

    def _calculate_fail_rate(self, stat):
        num_failures = stat['num_failures']
        num_requests = stat["num_requests"]
        return (num_failures / num_requests) * 100

    def _calculate_percentile(self, stat, percentile):
        response_times = stat['response_times']
        num_requests = stat['num_requests']
        return calculate_response_time_percentile(response_times, num_requests, percentile)

    def _kpi_check(self, stats):
        if len(stats) == 0:
            return

        for kpi in self.kpis:
            name = list(kpi.keys())[0]
            stat = next(stat for stat in stats if stat["name"] == name)
            if stat:
                kpi_settings = kpi[list(kpi.keys())[0]]
                for kpi_setting in kpi_settings:
                    self._metrics_check(kpi_setting, stat)

    def _metrics_check(self, kpi_setting, stat):
        (metric, value) = kpi_setting
        name = stat["name"]
        if metric == Metric.EROR_RATE.value:
            error_rate = stat['error_rate']
            error_rate <= value or self._log_error(error_rate, kpi_setting, name)
        if metric == Metric.PERCENTILE_90.value:
            percentile = stat['percentile_90']
            percentile <= value or self._log_error(percentile, kpi_setting, name)
        if metric == Metric.RPS.value:
            rps = stat['rps']
            rps >= value or self._log_error(rps, kpi_setting, name)

    def _log_error(self, stat_value, kpi_settings, name):
        (metric, value) = kpi_settings
        self.errors.append(
            f"{metric} for '{name}' is {stat_value}, but expected it to be better than {value}")  # noqa: E501

    def _interpret_errors(self):
        if len(self.errors) == 0:
            logging.info('All KPIs are good!')
        else:
            for error in self.errors:
                logging.error(f"SLA failed: \n {error}")
            self.env.process_exit_code = 1

    def _validate_kpis(self):
        for kpi in self.kpis:
            kpi_keys = list(kpi.keys())
            if len(kpi_keys) > 1:
                raise Exception("Every dict must contain definition for only one endpoint")
            kpi_settings = kpi[kpi_keys[0]]
            if len(kpi_settings) == 0:
                raise Exception(f"No KPI defined for endpoint {kpi_keys[0]}")
            for kpi_setting in kpi_settings:
                (metric, value) = kpi_setting
                if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
                    raise Exception(f"Provide valid value for '{metric}' metric for endpoint {kpi_keys[0]}")
                if not Metric.has_value(metric):
                    raise Exception(f"Metric {metric} not implemented")
```

Now you have to register KpiPlugin class within your Locust script and define KPI(s) like this:

```
events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    KPI_SETTINGS = [{'/store/inventory': [('percentile_90', 50), ('rps', 500), ('error_rate', 0)]}]
    KpiPlugin(env=environment, kpis=KPI_SETTINGS)
```

The above script will make your build fail in case /store/inventory endpoint won't meet one of the defined criteria — 90 percentile is worse than 50ms, RPS is under 500, the error rate is higher than 0%.